# scientific format within bash shell

Tags: shell, bc

Within bash shell, I need to add numbers in the format : `0.13281E-04` and `-0.79254E-04`.
So, in the script, I have:

```
  tt1=`echo $var_t1| sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\\*10\\^/'`
  tt2=`echo $var_t2| sed -e 's/[eE]+*/\\*10\\^/'`
  var_t=`echo "($tt1 + $tt2)/2.0" | bc -l`
```

which gives result as: `-.000032986500000`

Is there any straight forward way getting var_t as `-3.29865E-05`?

Comment: Perhaps `printf "%g\n" ${var_t}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option -v of printf like so

```
printf -v var_t "%g\n" -.00003298650000
echo $var_t
```